# How to find the last occurrence of item in nested list?

Tags: python

I have a randomly generated list with a similar format

```
data = [['item','A'],['colour',1],['colour',3],['item','D']]
```

I want to find where 'colour' last occurred and print the number associated with it

```
for item in data:
    if item[-1] == 'colour':
        print(item[1])
```

this loop I have now prints nothing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change it to:

```
for item in data[::-1]:
    if item[0] == 'colour':
        print(item[1])
        break
```

You have to change three things.

- The first loop iterates from last to first item `[::-1]` (You can also use `.reverse()` [reverse](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/reverse))
- and checks if the first item `item[0]` in the sublist is `"colour"`. (Your `[-1]` checks the last item in the sublist, that are the numbers in your case)
- If the first `"colour"` is found, the loop is `break`ed.